# How can I apply {% static %} to all static files in my django project or just let django navigate through all my files?

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles, static-files

I added a Minecraft Overviewer render to my django site and stored all of the png, js, and css files in the static folder. The render contains tens of thousands of these files and I don't want to manually do

```
{% static 'render/name.js' %}
```

40,000 times through various file paths. Is there a way to just let django navigate through all of these files?

Comment: `{% for file in files %}{% static file.url %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: I still have to do that individually for each file though

Comment: No, you don't. You can get all your files in static folder (os.walk or something) then send an extra context to your view.

Comment: Oh I got it to work.. sry I'm a bit of a noob at django